# How can I use unmanaged class in managed class?

Tags: c++, .net, winforms, opencv, visual-c++

I'm trying to put `cv::CascadeClassifier` object inside `System.Windows.Forms.Form` class.

Intellisense and compiler say, that I can't have unamanaged class inside managed class.

So, how can I use that unmanaged class in my Windows Forms application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your compiler is correct.  However, you can have a *pointer* to an unmanaged type as a member.  It's not optimal, but it's all you've got. You can use your constructor and destructor to allocate and cleanup if needed.

Comment: Sooo... I can create `cv::CascadeClassifier* haar;` and create object like this: `haar = new cv::CascadeClassifier;` inside my MainForm_Shown event handler, and just `delete haar` inside my MainForm_Closed event handler? Or I have to use constructor and destructor for this?

Comment: Though you could interact with the unmanaged memory block, .NET won't be able to invoke _any member_ on the unmanaged object unless it is marked with `ref`

Answer (score 1):

[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712790%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is some example code from MSDN. It agrees with Ed S.'s answer

> The this pointer in U is a __nogc pointer , so f cannot be called without first pinning M.

Example (From same page)

```
// mcpp_nested_classes5.cpp
// compile with: /clr /LD
#using <mscorlib.dll>

__gc struct M {
   __nogc struct U {   // nested unmanaged class
      int m_data;
      U() { System::Console::WriteLine("U::U"); }
      void f() { int* p = &m_data; }
   };

   int ia __nogc[100]; // embedded unmanaged array
};

M::U u; // use unmanaged nested type
```

Comment: Where should I put this? I have "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier" on `__gc struct` error.

Comment: The `__gc` syntax was superseded by `ref` quite some time ago (VS2005).  Most of the other double underscores were removed too.   _[The double underscore in front of all keywords has been removed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235298(v=vs.80).aspx)_